# TestCafe Screenshot: Browser Provider for Android. crop.js "Unable to locate the page area in the browser window screenshot"

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I work on an extension of the [testcafe-provider-android](https://github.com/bsmithb2/testcafe-browser-provider-android). I want it to support Firefox and screenshots.

Screenshots are taken with the Android Debugging Tools. It works fine with Chrome, but not with Firefox.

[crop.js#calculateMarkPosition()](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/src/screenshots/crop.js#L20) can not find the mark.

I think I understood how the mark thing works.

In [utils.js#generateScreenshotMark()](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/src/screenshots/utils.js#L8) a string of 32 zeros or ones is generated, this is the "id".
“1” becomes a white dot and “0” becomes a black dot.
The "markSeed" is the id transformed into a Byte Array.
"markData" Is the base64 encoded image, ready to be used in an URL.

On the client, [screenshot-mark.js](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/src/client/ui/screenshot-mark.js#L8) places this image in the bottom right corner of the page.

[crop.js#calculateMarkPosition()](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/src/screenshots/crop.js#L20) scans the screenshot line by line in order to find the mark and to crop the image properly.

Here are IDs and Screenshots for Chrome and Firefox:

Note: I manipulated the code to always generate the same ID. The Screenshots are cropped and zoomed in.

ID:

`00101111000011000011000011110100`

Chrome:

[image: Screenshot from Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: Screenshot from Firefox]

In my eyes, they look the same. So why does this not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason for this behaviour.

In Chrome the black dots have the rgba value rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), while in Firefox they are rgba (1, 1, 1, 1);

This is why the index can not be found - the values are not as expected.

Now I need to find out, if this is a bug in Firefox.

UPDATE:

This happens because Firefox makes color adjustments.
The problem is described in [TestCafe Bug #2918](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2918) and was resolved with [TestCafe Pull Request #3732](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/pull/3732)

We now just need to wait for the next release.

Answer (score 3):

If you can crop screenshots using third-party tools, you need to disable [built-in screenshot mark generation](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/v1.1.0/src/test-run/index.js#L532) by setting the [`hasChromelessScreenshots`](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/v1.1.0/src/browser/provider/plugin-host.js#L115) property to false.

I'd recommend you open [a new issue on the TestCafe repository](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) and provide all screenshot sources.